# One user can't run program while others can

Tags: autocad, rights

i am having an issue a little bit strange.
I installed autocad lt 2015 in some computers in my network with administrator account, and i'm having issues with one user in particular. When he starts autocad, nothing happen, although if i run as administrator it works like a charm.

I did the next tests:
-Uninstalled and reinstall autocad.
-Gave user admin rights to the program.
-Login with other users (same permissions as this one) and they are able to run it.
-Check the user account on the active directory and it's exactly the same as the others.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: This question should probably be asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) rather than stackoverflow, since it doesn't appear relate to programing.

Comment: i will do that. I didn't know superuser. Thanks @Pokechu22

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the user could have a profile locally on that machine that is causing issues?

Comment: i checked that, he had. But i already delete it and re-login with his domain credentials.